# How can I preserve height contributed by text, when text set to blank

Tags: css

Consider an inline-block CSS element which can contain text, and which has some nice padding.

Depending on whether or not there's any text in the inline-block, the height of the element will vary:

```css
.text-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text-holder.black { background-color: #000000; }
.text-holder.grey { background-color: #606060; }
```

```html
<div class='text-holder black'>I HAVE TEXT</div>
<div class='text-holder grey'></div>
```

How can I ensure that the height of such elements is the same, whether or not there is any text inside the element, and regardless of the font-size?

At first I considered `min-height`, but I don't believe that will work for variable font sizes.

Comment: Why not just `height`?

Comment: My font sizes may get very big, potentially outside of a fixed `height`. Plus I'd like to maintain a constant amount of padding around the text, regardless of the size of the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a zero space character when empty:

```css
.text-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text-holder.black { background-color: #000000; }
.text-holder.grey { background-color: #606060; }

.text-holder:empty::before {
  content:"\200B";
}
```

```html
<div class='text-holder black'>I HAVE TEXT</div>
<div class='text-holder grey'></div>
```

You can also keep it for all the element since it has 0 width:

```css
.text-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text-holder.black { background-color: #000000; }
.text-holder.grey { background-color: #606060; }

.text-holder::before {
  content:"\200B";
}
```

```html
<div class='text-holder black'>I HAVE TEXT</div>
<div class='text-holder grey'></div>
```

Simply pay attention if have leading spaces:

```css
.text-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text-holder.black { background-color: #000000; }
.text-holder.grey { background-color: #606060; }

.text-holder::before {
  content:"\200B";
}
```

```html
<div class='text-holder black'>I HAVE TEXT</div><br>
<div class='text-holder black'> I HAVE TEXT</div>
<div class='text-holder grey'></div>
```

Comment: what happens when the font size changes

Comment: @duxfox-- try and see

Comment: I did, it breaks - i copied your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/u1fos9L0/1/

Comment: @duxfox-- because you are not using the same font-size for all the elements which is logical. It's about having the same height dealing with the same font-size

Comment: OP said: 'but I don't believe that will work for **variable font sizes**' but i'm not sure if that means different words will have different font sizes or if they will all have the same font size. Maybe I misunderstood what he means

Comment: @duxfox-- he was talking about min-height when he said this. If you set a fixed height or min-height it won't work if you later change the font-size. Before he said: *How can I ensure that the height of such elements is the same, whether or not there is any text inside the element* --> so I guess it's about having the same size for empty and non-empty divs

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you've got the right idea of what I was trying to communicate! Sorry duxfox if it wasn't clear what I was looking for. This is a very clever solution!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of this working out for you is to use flexbox. See the code below. Basically, have a parent set as `display: flex;` and that should keep all the heights on ***each line*** the same. So if line 2 has only small font sizes then that one line will all be equal heights, but the heights will all be smaller than line 1 for example

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.lg {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.md {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sm {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <span class='child lg'>some text</span>
  <span class='child sm'>text more text</span>
  <span class='child md'>child asdf</span>
  <span class='child lg'>asl;fkj s</span>
  <span class='child lg'>asdf</span>
  <span class='child md'>asdf 1</span>
  <span class='child sm'>alsdfj </span>
  <span class='child lg'>asldfkj</span>
  <span class='child sm'>asldfkj</span>
</div>
```